# Hadoop PIG Max of Tuple

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How do I find the `MAX` of a tuple in Pig?

My code looks like this:

```
A,20
B,10
C,40
D,5

data = LOAD 'myData.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS key, value;
all = GROUP data ALL;
maxKey = FOREACH all GENERATE MAX(data.value);
DUMP maxKey;
```

This returns 40, but I want the full key-value pair: `C,40`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works with Pig 0.10.0:

```
data = LOAD 'myData.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (key, value: long);
A = GROUP data ALL;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE MAX(data.value) AS val;
C = FILTER data BY value == (long)C.val;
DUMP C;
```

Comment: Just a heads-up: while computing 'C' data should be filtered by B.val instead of C.val

Comment: I'd like to second @Zibi. The last declaration should be `C = FILTER data BY value == (long)B.val;`, not `C = FILTER data BY value == (long)C.val;`. Thanks for the solution @Frederic Schmaljohann. That worked for me on Pig 0.10.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
data = LOAD 'myData.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (key: chararray, value: int);

sorted = ORDER data BY value DESC;

limited = LIMIT sorted 1;

projected = FOREACH limited GENERATE key;

DUMP projected;
```